highcharts stock-tools not working(next.js)
I was using highcharts in my next.js project and everything was fine. but suddenly I noticed the stock tools are not working. they are showing and I can select them but they are not working and they have no effect on chart???
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Sidebar } from "@/components/sidebar-component";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Script from "next/script";
import { SelectSymbolComponent } from "@/components/select-symbol-component";
import { ModeToggle } from "@/components/theme-change-button";

import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsStock from "highcharts/modules/stock";
import StockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";
import HighchartsIndicators from "highcharts/indicators/indicators";
import HighchartsStockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";
import HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import "highcharts/css/stocktools/gui.css";
import { px } from "framer-motion";

HighchartsStock(Highcharts);
HighchartsIndicators(Highcharts);
HighchartsStockTools(Highcharts);
StockTools(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

export default function () {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css"
      />
      <div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-full overflow-hidden">
        <div className="flex flex-grow overflow-hidden">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="flex-1 overflow-hidden">
            <Chart currentPage={pathname} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="fixed right-5 bottom-4 z-50">
        <ModeToggle />
      </div>

      {/* Highcharts scripts */}
      <Script
        src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
      <Script
        src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock-tools.js"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
      <Script
        src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drag-panes.js"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
      <Script
        src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/full-screen.js"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
      />
    </>
  );
}

const Chart = ({ currentPage }: { currentPage: string }) => {
  const pageTitle = currentPage.split("/").pop() || "Chart";

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadChart = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(
        "https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json"
      ).then((response) => response.json());

      const yearChangePoints = findYearChangePoints(data);

      const ohlc: [number, number, number, number, number][] = [];
      const volume: [number, number][] = [];
      data.forEach((dataPoint: number[]) => {
        ohlc.push([
          dataPoint[0],
          dataPoint[1],
          dataPoint[2],
          dataPoint[3],
          dataPoint[4],
        ]);
        volume.push([dataPoint[0], dataPoint[5]]);
      });

      if (typeof Highcharts !== "undefined") {
        const chart = Highcharts.stockChart("container", {
          chart: {
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
            height: "50%",
          },
          stockTools: {
            gui: {
              enabled: true,
              buttons: [
                "indicators",
                "separator",
                "simpleShapes",
                "lines",
                "crookedLines",
                "measure",
                "advanced",
                "toggleAnnotations",
                "separator",
                "verticalLabels",
                "flags",
                "separator",
                "zoomChange",
                "fullScreen",
                "typeChange",
                "separator",
                "currentPriceIndicator",
                "saveChart",
              ],
            },
          },
          yAxis: [
            { labels: { align: "left" }, resize: { enabled: true } },
            { labels: { align: "left" }, top: "80%", height: "20%", offset: 0 },
          ],
          xAxis: {
            plotLines: yearChangePoints.map((point) => ({
              color: "#000000",
              width: 1,
              value: point,
              label: {
                text: new Date(point).getFullYear().toString(),
                rotation: 90,
                align: "left",
                x: 10,
                style: { color: "#000000" },
              },
            })),
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            shared: true,
            formatter: function () {
              return `<b>${this.x}</b><br/>${this.points
                .map(
                  (point: any) =>
                    `<span style="color:${point.series.color}">●</span> ${
                      point.series.name
                    }: ${point.y}`
                )
                .join("<br/>")}`;
            },
          },
          series: [
            {
              type: "candlestick",
              id: "aapl-ohlc",
              name: "AAPL Stock Price",
              data: ohlc,
            },
            {
              type: "column",
              id: "aapl-volume",
              name: "AAPL Volume",
              data: volume,
              yAxis: 1,
            },
          ],
        });

        chart.reflow();
      }
    };

    loadChart();
  }, []);

  return (<div id="container" className="chart z-50 h-2" style={{ height: '1000px' }} />
  );
};



function findYearChangePoints(data: [number, number][]): number[] {
  const yearChangePoints: number[] = [];
  let currentYear = new Date(data[0][0]).getFullYear();

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const date = new Date(data[i][0]);
    if (date.getFullYear() !== currentYear) {
      yearChangePoints.push(data[i][0]);
      currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    }
  }

  return yearChangePoints;
}

and I don't know what to try I was trying anything checking of the js and css files are loaded correctly or what changing functions and code asking ai like chatgpt and others but they didn't help at all just made the code worse...so if you know or can guess what's the problem please help thank you

Please reproduce this problem in an online editor I could work on. Feel free to use this demo as a basic template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ded5d?file=index.js

@dominik-chudy  I made a public repo for that you can try it using https://github.com/AMSN81/highhcharts_stock. I tried to add the repo to stackblitz but it had some weird bugs which I didn't have when I tried it in my localhost and sorry that I couldn't use an online editor.

@DominikChudy you can also try it using:  https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/AMSN81/highhcharts_stock?file=app/page.tsx:L1-L200

Unfortunately I'm getting an error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'highcharts' Still  I found an interesting topic on HC forum about stocktools in next.js that might be really helpful to you, check it out here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=46006

@DominikChudy actually it works. I checked it and it shows some errors but if you wait it will show up. personally waited for about 1~2 minutes and it showed up in stackblitz.

and thanks for the reference but in my case the chart is showing up the problem is that the tools which were in left and they're called stock-tools I guess are not working...

UPDATE it's fixed I forgot to place 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations-advanced.js"></script>
